wcf class in separate project not active when running as a service
I have a service application which contains multiple projects. One of the projects is a WFC project.
When running the main module as a application, the WFC part can be accessed. However, when running the same code as a service, the WFC class cannot be accessed. Neither by using the VS function connect or update a service reference, nor by running my client program.
Both applications are working, so the problem must be related to the fact it's running as a service.
To install the service I use the code:
 ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Service() };
 ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        

The WFC service is activated by using:
 serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WcfService));
 serviceHost.Open();

PS. I don't know if this is the best method, but running this service as an application, I'm skipping the part where I install the service and the last line of the main program module is:
Thread.Sleep(100000000); 


This might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-windows-service
